# Using Dockerfile RUN --mount to cache cmake output

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to understand Dockerfile to optimize my building.

Currently I have a complete non-Docker dev environment. I've installed packages and the compiler via `apt-get install`, and I have a build script which does the `cd build && ninja` appropriately.

I wish to convert to a proper Docker environment. Here's the excerpt:

```
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y ETC_ETC_ETC
COPY . /app
RUN cd /app
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=./build,sharing=locked \
   mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake .. && make -j4
CMD ["/app/build/bin/exec"]
```

My requirements are: I'll hack on the source code (`.`) and will run `docker build -f ../Dockerfile`. I wish to keep the `make` output, so that modifying ONE source file will not trigger `cmake` nor `make` from scratch. `make` is clever enough to not trigger whole recompilation if only 1-2 source files have been modified.

Is it possible to convert Dockerfile to achieve this persistent build tree? I'm battling VOLUME and mount binds to no avail.

Wish to cache and reuse build output as above.
I'll also extract the `make install` folder out of the container in due course.

EDIT:

The idea is the following:

1. set up environment, repo, dependenceis.
2. cmake
3. make && make install -- the first run will be lengthy ie. 10mins
4. run and test the code - a single app
5. hack on repo code, git commit, etc
6. goto 3. -- the subsequent runs will be fast i.e. 3-4 seconds. –

In case it's not obvious, the idea is to iterate quickly -- hack code, make && make install, run. Restart. With a classic Docker environment, the make step always starts from scratch. No good.

Comment: https://www.docker.com/blog/introduction-to-heredocs-in-dockerfiles/. Use that to create a readable shell script. Start off with `set -e` to get exit on errors to render all the `&&` chains obsolete. That said, your requirements are not specified in a way that they can be verified, making it unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your question is how the `CMD` step (running the container) can access the cache-mount that is used in the `RUN --mount` step?

Comment: @SebDieBin: maybe. cache-mount or volume or binding. any method.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the concept of docker.

`docker build` creates an "image" by executing the commands in your Dockerfile. This is used to **setup** the build environment.

`docker run` then creates a new container based on the image and starts it. This is used when you actually want to trigger a build.

So you have to ask the question: What commands do I have to execute to transform a fresh Ubuntu into an environment, where I can trigger a build? Those commands go into the dockerfile.

The other question is: What commands do I need to run to build my software (i.e. `cmake` and `make`)? Those need to go into some form of a script that is COPY'ied to the image by the Dockerfile and then mentioned in the CMD statement of the Dockerfile.

Comment: Just for completeness, there is a third possible way to run Docker: You can execute something in an already running container using `docker exec`. In the context of development, I've used such a container to encapsulate the build cache, so stopping the container discarded the cache. While running, I just `docker exec`ed the build commands inside the container, which hat the source code mounted as a volume.

Comment: I thought it was explicit in the Dockerfile. (1) set up environment, repo, dependenceis. (2) cmake (3) make && make install -- the first run will be lengthy ie. 10mins (4) run and test the code - a single app (5) hack on repo code, git commit, etc (6) goto 3 -- the subsequent runs will be fast i.e. 3-4 seconds.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, the idea is to iterate quickly -- hack code, make && make install, run. Restart. With a classic Docker environment, the make step always starts from scratch. No good.